# Use of undefined constant in PHP while generationg directory path

Tags: php

i am using this code to define the directory paths of my project:

config.php is

```
<?php
define('CB_HOME', realpath(dirname(__DIR__)));
define('FD_HOME', CB_HOME."/testbot");
```

I use am using CB_home And FD_home in other files.

i am getting the error:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CB_HOME - assumed 'CB_HOME' in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test-bot\\testbot\\bootstrap.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  require_once(CB_HOME/AbstractCbRest.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test-bot\\testbot\\bootstrap.php on line 3
 PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'CB_HOME/AbstractCbRest.php' (include_path='.;C:\\xampp\\php\\PEAR') in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test-bot\\testbot\\bootstrap.php on line 3
```

my bootstrap.php is :

```
<?php 
require_once 'config.php';
require_once CB_HOME.'/AbstractCbRest.php';
```

where is it going wrong?

Comment: And the constant is defined in `config.php`? Are you sure you're looking at the *correct* `config.php`?

Comment: Try to concat the FD home value before you define it.

Comment: i tried doing the same still the same error persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that **[include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)** settings are interfering with your script. So (as mentioned by @deceze) you might be loading an incorrect (although existing) config.php file.

Maybe you could try using an absolute path to include your configuration or use something along the lines of:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.php';
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT.indeed the include_path settings were interfering with the script.Had to give the absolute path.

Answer (score -1):

It is obvious that the windows path with two "\" doesn't work. To remove a double backslash (NOTE: this is no solution but a workaround), do this:

```
$someValue = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test-bot\\testbot\\'; $someValue = preg_replace('/\\\\/u', '\\', $someValue);
```

or in your case:

```
define('CB_HOME', preg_replace('/\\\\/u', '\\', realpath(dirname(DIR))));
```

Comment: Why using `DIR` instead of `__DIR__` should help? `__DIR__` is a *magic constant* in PHP...

Comment: man, i dont know but there was a post before suggesting that... got deleted though.

Comment: @user1327205 if you really wanna go with that preg_replace, although I don't recommend it. get $someValue = realpath(dirname(__DIR__)); and then trigger the preg_replace as shown above in the first line. echo the stuff and you see, if it at least removes those \\ (double backslashes). I can't reproduce it for you, since I work with a vm-lamp and not xamp. In my environment your code works fine.

Comment: I was wondering i used CB_HOME in bootstrap.php ,should i put it in quotes in it.

require_once CB_HOME.'/AbstractCbRest.php';

should i change it to
require_once 'CB_HOME'.'/AbstractCbRest.php';

Comment: Changing `CB_HOME` into `'CB_HOME'` in your bootstrap file will make it a string "CB_HOME" and not the path you want to obtain...

Comment: if you mix variables and strings they are written as followed 'yourString'.$yourVariable.'yourSecondString' and so on... look at http://jp2.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php, first example tells: "define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/config.php'); "

Comment: BUt  i changed CB_HOME into 'CB_HOME' ,the error is removed now

Comment: @user1327205 you changed it in your bootstrap file?

Comment: yep!i changed it in the bootstrap.php

Comment: @Shiven What's the point? This will try to `require_once "CB_HOME/AbstractCbRest.php";` Are you sure you have a directory named "CB_HOME"? Didn't you want to use a constant with realpath instead?